# Cоздание истории в Инстаграм c помощью Selenium C# gecko

Tags: c#, selenium, instagram, эмулятор, gecko

Я пытаюсь разместить **историю в Инстаграмм** с компьютера.
Использую *Selenium + C# + geckodriver* (Console Application).
Изменил хедеры на мобильные и размер окна браузера. Интерфейс действительно стал мобильным за исключением одной вещи - при добавлении получаю уведомление

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом, если нажать Ctrl+Shift+M (режим адаптивного дизайна) такого сообщения нет и добавление истории происходит как с телефона.

Пытался изменить размер окна браузера на обратный (410,740)->(740,410) - безуспешно.

Пытался отправить браузеру это сочетание клавиш с помощью  `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/")).SendKeys(Keys.Control + Keys.Shift + "M");`

И с помощью

```
Actions a = new Actions(driver);          
   a.KeyDown(Keys.Shift)
    .KeyDown(Keys.Control)
    .SendKeys("m")
    .Build()
    .Perform();
```

Также копал в сторону добавления определенных options.AddArgument, но не нашел ничего подходящего для Firefox.

UPD:
Благодаря комментарию копнул в

```
 FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.AddAdditionalCapability("device", "iPhone X");
    //options.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "iPhone X");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(path, options);
```

На что ловлю ексепшн

$exception  {"Invalid moz:firefoxOptions field device"}

Очень хочется докопаться до сути. Помогите, перерыл все

Answer (score 1, accepted):

подозреваю что хоткей режима адаптивного дизайна является частью не столько браузера, сколько аддона. И он должен включатся только в случае если вьюха аддона открыта.

Предполагаю что за этот режим отвечает некая настройка конкретного браузера и ее можно проставить из настроек по которым ты инициализируешь селениум.

UPD:
да, я угадал.

```
firefox_options.set_capability("deviceName", "iPhone")
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы мне немножечко помочь.

 Нашел тонну док по java 
погуглил аналоги наткнулся на такие 


FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "iPhone X");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(path, options);


приводит к ошибке  $exception {"Invalid moz:firefoxOptions field deviceName"} 
А также


DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
 capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "iPhone X");
Не отрабатывает(((

Comment: Туговато чтото эта тема дается

Comment: не, детальнее не подскажу, я с селениумом имел дело слишком давно. А с компатибилити вообще не сталкивался.  Отметь даный вопрос как правильный, и оформ новый вопрос где ты распишешь уже полный код который у тебя не срабатывает, а то в даном формате увидеть какие-то проблемы сложно. А у меня возможности проверить самому код нет вообще